# Is there a way to create reports in PDF for iOS?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I am looking for a way to create a report in an iPad, a lib in c, c++ or objc or something.

What i want to do, is to fill an invoice data, and let the user choose his template from a set. The report must be a PDF.

edit:
I actually need something like crystal reports, or a way to have lots of predefined templates and be able to render them.

edit2:
In the end i had to create an own report-system to handle the creation of the pdf.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the official [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2DDrawing/Conceptual/DrawingPrintingiOS/GeneratingPDF/GeneratingPDF.html) for creating pdf's.

Comment: I have seen that, what i need is something like crystal reports and the like.

Answer (score 0):

If you can rely on the internet connection, check out [jsreport](http://jsreport.net). It is capable of storing as many report templates you like. It also contains editor where you can prepare your templates using html, css and javascript templating engines.

For actual pdf rendering,  you just send data from iPad to jsreport rest api and get back pdf.

Note: I am the author of jsreport